# Copy files to directories whose names start with the last 3 characters of those files names

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with files named like below:

```
xxx009.dcm
xxx010.dcm
xxx011.dcm 
.
.
.
xxx250.dcm
```

I would like to copy each file with file name ending with specific digits and paste them in a folder containing the same digit, e.g.:

```
Copy xxx009.dcm to C:\Test\File9ab
Copy xxx010.dcm to C:\Test\File10ab
Copy xxx011.dcm to C:\Test\File11ab
.
.
.
Copy xxx250.dcm to C:\Test\File250ab
```

I am a real beginner, and need to create a batch file to do this job for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is clear that your directory names do not contain the last three characters of the file names! Your examples do not match your question, and it is therefore unanswerable unless you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56025594/edit) to bring it to a reasonable standard according to [ask] and include, along with it, a [mcve] of the code you require us to help you to fix.

Comment: Well, "I'm a beginner" is not an excuse for not following the rules of this site. SO is not a free code/script writing service, it is a Q&A site for programmers. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]! Come back here with a [mcve] of your coding attempts, [edit] your question for that!

Comment: @Compo Sorry for being so unprofessional. Will make sure to follow the rules the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. iterate files with a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and use `~n` [modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
2. use [substring](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)s to get the last 3 places from a string (need to copy to a regular var)
3. use [set /a](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) to remove leading zeroes by subtracting 1000 from value prepended with a 1
4. as 2. + 3. are done inside a code block this also requires [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\05\07\SO_56025594.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Source=A:\Test"
Set "Target=A:\Test\File"

for %%F in ("%Source%\*.dcm") do (
   Set "file=%%~nF"
   Set /A "No=1!file:~-3! -1000"
   if not exist "%Target%!No!ab" MD "%Target%!No!ab"
   copy "%%~F" "%Target%!No!ab"
)
```

Sample tree after running above batch:

```
> tree /F
A:.
└───test
    │   xxx009.dcm
    │   xxx010.dcm
    │   xxx011.dcm
    │
    ├───File10ab
    │       xxx010.dcm
    │
    ├───File11ab
    │       xxx011.dcm
    │
    └───File9ab
            xxx009.dcm
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! It is exactly doing what I was struggling to do for days! Much appreciated!